# unable to interate a list

Tags: python, selenium

am trying to webscrape the information using selenium ,code is working for single item, but when am passing the list am getting the below output,

Actual Output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

```
term=["Atta","Sugar"]
    
def get_link(term,page):
        for term in term:
            pin(Pincode)
            grocery="https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=GROCERY&as-show=on&as=off"
            term = term.replace(' ', '+')
            stem = grocery.format(term)
            url_template = stem + '&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&as-backfill=on&page='
            next=url_template+str(page)
            #print(next)
            return next
        
            
    def PID():
        for page in range(1,5):
            path=get_link(term,page)
            driver.get(path)
            id=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-id]')
            for i in id:
                results=i.get_attribute('data-id')
                #print(results)
                PIDs.append(results)
                Search_Term.append(term)
    
    PID()
    
    ID={'Query':Search_Term,'PID_s':PIDs}
    
    Output=pd.DataFrame(ID)
    print(Output)
```

Comment: `Output.explode('Query'`) ?

Comment: Try to change Search_Term to Search_Term[0] at the ID={} line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it would be better to put the `for loop` for `term` inside the `PID` function. Try like below once:

```
terms = ["Atta", "Sugar"]


def get_link(term, page):
    # Not sure what pin(Pincode) line is doing
    grocery = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=GROCERY&as-show=on&as=off"
    term = term.replace(' ', '+')
    #print(term)
    stem = grocery.format(term)
    url_template = stem + '&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&as-backfill=on&page='
    next = url_template + str(page)
    # print(next)
    return next


def PID():
    for term in terms:
        for page in range(1, 5):
            path = get_link(term, page)
            driver.get(path)
            id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-id]')
            for i in id:
                results = i.get_attribute('data-id')
                print(f"{term}:{results}")
            # PIDs.append(results)
            # Search_Term.append(term)

PID()
```

```
Atta:FLRFDPRFNGYJ95KD
Atta:FLRETEFHENWKNJQE
...
Sugar:SUGG4SFGSP6TCQ48
Sugar:SUGEUD25B6YCCNGM
...
```